# get the size of a pointer to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I have this code:

```
static void convertData(const I* vec, std::string vectorName, std::string filename)
{
     for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(*vec) / sizeof(vec[0]); i++)
     {
                    if ((i + 4) % 4 == 0)
                        fcpp << '\n';
                    if (i == sizeof(*vec) / sizeof(vec[0]) - 1)
                        fcpp << vec[i];
                    else
                        fcpp << vec[i] << ", ";
    }
}
```

and this is how I callit:

```
std::vector<float> v = {/*...*/};
convertData(v.data(),"myVec", "vectors");
```

so I expected to get the length of my vector but I got the length of the pointer which is 4.

how to do to get the length of the vector?

Thanks

Comment: Short Answer: You can't.

Comment: naturally, there's a solution to this?

Comment: Directly pass the vector like `const std::vector<float>& vec` and use `vec.size()`.

Comment: @chak There are, either pass the vector directly, you you add a size parameter to the function.